# ELSE IF not working in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got a weird error when I try to use a `ELSE IF` in a PROCEDURE, and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm creating the procedure with TOAD.

This code works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findMin(valore1 in integer, valore2 in integer, risultato out integer) IS
BEGIN
    IF(valore1 < valore2) THEN
        risultato:= valore1;
    ELSE
        risultato:= valore2;             
    END IF;
END;   
/
```

This doesn't. I get this error on the last line of code: `Found: ';' - Expecting IF`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findMin(valore1 in integer, valore2 in integer, risultato out integer) IS
BEGIN
    IF(valore1 < valore2) THEN
        risultato:= valore1;
    ELSE IF (valore1 > valore2) THEN
        risultato:= valore2;    
    ELSE
        risultato := 0;              
    END IF;
END;  --here I get the error 
/
```

What is my error?

Thank you

Comment: By the way, PL/SQL doesn't need brackets in `if` expressions, because they are terminated by `then` (or `end if`). Languages tend to use one or the other approach but not both.

Answer (score 8):

If you indent the `else` block you can see that you're missing an `end if`:

```
BEGIN
    IF(valore1 < valore2) THEN
        risultato:= valore1;
    ELSE
        IF (valore1 > valore2) THEN
            risultato:= valore2;    
        ELSE
            risultato := 0;              
        END IF;
    -- missing an END IF
END;
```

You either need to add that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findMin(valore1 in integer, valore2 in integer,
  risultato out integer) IS
BEGIN
    IF valore1 < valore2 THEN
        risultato:= valore1;
    ELSE
        IF valore1 > valore2 THEN
            risultato:= valore2;    
        ELSE
            risultato := 0;              
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/

Procedure FINDMIN compiled
```

Or more simply, change to `elsif`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findMin(valore1 in integer, valore2 in integer,
  risultato out integer) IS
BEGIN
    IF valore1 < valore2 THEN
        risultato:= valore1;
    ELSIF valore1 > valore2 THEN
        risultato:= valore2;    
    ELSE
        risultato := 0;              
    END IF;
END;
/

Procedure FINDMIN compiled
```

You could also use a case statement here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findMin(valore1 in integer, valore2 in integer, risultato out integer) IS
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN valore1 < valore2 THEN
            risultato:= valore1;
        WHEN valore1 > valore2 THEN
            risultato:= valore2;    
        ELSE
            risultato := 0;              
    END CASE;
END;
/

Procedure FINDMIN compiled
```

or even just a case expression as this example is a simple single assignment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findMin(valore1 in integer, valore2 in integer,
  risultato out integer) IS
BEGIN
    risultato := CASE
            WHEN valore1 < valore2 THEN valore1
            WHEN valore1 > valore2 THEN valore2
            ELSE 0
        END;
END;
/

Procedure FINDMIN compiled
```

Read more about [conditional statements in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-B7DD4E62-3ED2-41E9-AAE5-90A78788BB31).

Comment: Thank you. I thought that "ELSE IF" was only one command, actually they are 2.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is a typo mistake, replace `ELSE IF` with PLSQL's [ELSIF](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/if_statement.htm)

```
ELSIF (valore1 > valore2) THEN
```

> ELSIF
>
> Introduces a Boolean expression that is evaluated if none of the preceding conditions returned TRUE.

Comment: I got it. Thank you